# code stopped working after migrating from codepen

Tags: html

So, this is the weirdest thing ever. I was working on a project on codepen(of course in codepen is a lot easier).

How do you migrate from codepen? Well, you pretty much just add the basic html tags and links so you can communicate between the css and js.

But although I'm doing all of that correctly(also adding the required libraries), my code does not work correctly.

What my code should be doing:
 - Allow the user to drag the windows

But it's not!

Even more, all of the Jquery and Jquery UI functions are not working correctly. When I looked at the console, I found the following error `"ReferenceError: $ is not defined"`.

Alright, now the code I'm using is here: http://codepen.io/julian-a-avar/pen/xbaRJz

And as expected everything is the same but the HTML file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- INFO -->
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="application-name" content="Orion OS">
        <meta name="author" content="Julian Avar Campopiano">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="keywords" content="">

        <!-- CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">

        <!-- JS -->
        <script src="script.js"></script>

        <!-- Libraries -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="taskbar">
            <div id="start_menu"></div>
            <div id="menu">
                <div class="app app1">W1</div>
                <div class="app app2">W2</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="window w1">
            <div class="head">
                <div class="title">Window 1</div>
                <div class="buttons">
                    <div class="close"></div>
                    <div class="maximize"></div>
                    <div class="minimize"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse tristique massa ipsum, eu posuere tellus interdum vel. Nullam quis lectus feugiat, malesuada enim ac, malesuada sapien. Cras elit tellus, consequat id justo non, convallis interdum nisi. Sed pulvinar, ipsum in imperdiet malesuada, lorem turpis gravida urna, consectetur auctor leo lectus et est. Nunc in pulvinar nulla, in pharetra dolor. Nunc accumsan felis interdum commodo pretium. Praesent rutrum neque et orci congue imperdiet. Fusce et gravida dui. Donec gravida in mauris vitae aliquam. Quisque semper est ut orci lacinia facilisis.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="window w2">
            <div class="head">
                <div class="title">Window 2</div>
                <div class="buttons">
                    <div class="close"></div>
                    <div class="maximize"></div>
                    <div class="minimize"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse tristique massa ipsum, eu posuere tellus interdum vel. Nullam quis lectus feugiat, malesuada enim ac, malesuada sapien. Cras elit tellus, consequat id justo non, convallis interdum nisi. Sed pulvinar, ipsum in imperdiet malesuada, lorem turpis gravida urna, consectetur auctor leo lectus et est. Nunc in pulvinar nulla, in pharetra dolor. Nunc accumsan felis interdum commodo pretium. Praesent rutrum neque et orci congue imperdiet. Fusce et gravida dui. Donec gravida in mauris vitae aliquam. Quisque semper est ut orci lacinia facilisis.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Yes, the file name are correct, and I'm using C9.io

Please help out, maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ReferenceError: $ is not defined

I figured that it happened in your *script.js* where you implement the drag and drop functions.

So fixing the order of the scripts might fix the issue.

```
<head>
    <!-- INFO -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="application-name" content="Orion OS">
    <meta name="author" content="Julian Avar Campopiano">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">

    <!-- Libraries -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <!-- JS -->
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

You included your script before jQuery, so `$` doesn't exist.

Order matters.

Answer (score 1):

You should add your script after you have loaded the jquery libraries.

It is also good practice to load  scripts at the end of your file, just before `</body>`.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- INFO -->
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="application-name" content="Orion OS">
        <meta name="author" content="Julian Avar Campopiano">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="keywords" content="">

        <!-- CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">

        <!-- JS -->
        <script src="script.js"></script>

        <!-- Libraries -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="taskbar">
            <div id="start_menu"></div>
            <div id="menu">
                <div class="app app1">W1</div>
                <div class="app app2">W2</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="window w1">
            <div class="head">
                <div class="title">Window 1</div>
                <div class="buttons">
                    <div class="close"></div>
                    <div class="maximize"></div>
                    <div class="minimize"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse tristique massa ipsum, eu posuere tellus interdum vel. Nullam quis lectus feugiat, malesuada enim ac, malesuada sapien. Cras elit tellus, consequat id justo non, convallis interdum nisi. Sed pulvinar, ipsum in imperdiet malesuada, lorem turpis gravida urna, consectetur auctor leo lectus et est. Nunc in pulvinar nulla, in pharetra dolor. Nunc accumsan felis interdum commodo pretium. Praesent rutrum neque et orci congue imperdiet. Fusce et gravida dui. Donec gravida in mauris vitae aliquam. Quisque semper est ut orci lacinia facilisis.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="window w2">
            <div class="head">
                <div class="title">Window 2</div>
                <div class="buttons">
                    <div class="close"></div>
                    <div class="maximize"></div>
                    <div class="minimize"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse tristique massa ipsum, eu posuere tellus interdum vel. Nullam quis lectus feugiat, malesuada enim ac, malesuada sapien. Cras elit tellus, consequat id justo non, convallis interdum nisi. Sed pulvinar, ipsum in imperdiet malesuada, lorem turpis gravida urna, consectetur auctor leo lectus et est. Nunc in pulvinar nulla, in pharetra dolor. Nunc accumsan felis interdum commodo pretium. Praesent rutrum neque et orci congue imperdiet. Fusce et gravida dui. Donec gravida in mauris vitae aliquam. Quisque semper est ut orci lacinia facilisis.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Libraries -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

        <!-- JS -->
        <script src="script.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```